# Error when trying to run a calculation on a column that has text and integers: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run a case statement calculation on a column that contains strings of text and I receive the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk' to data type int.

Tried both `Cast` and `Convert as int` to get around the issue but still receive an error.

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(tmp5.Core_Offer AS INT) IS NULL 
          THEN 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk' 
          ELSE CAST(tmp5.Core_Offer as int)*.75 
    END AS OUTPUT
```

and

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
       WHEN TRY_PARSE((tmp5.Core_Offer) AS INT) IS NULL 
          THEN 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk' 
          ELSE (tmp5.Core_Offer*.75) 
    END AS OUTPUT
FROM 
    #TMP5 tmp5
```

Comment: All options from a case statement must return the same datatype. You can't return a string for one condition and a number for another.

Comment: case _expression_. (Since it returns a value.)

Comment: Considering the difference in the type of values you're returning, it would seem a better choice to use 2 separate columns

Comment: can you return all as varchar then? Using two columns is not really an option.  I tried combining two separate columns but same issue.

Comment: The issue is due to short circuiting behaviour. You can either change the column to varchar or handle it differently for avoiding this short circuiting issues as mentioned [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-t-sql-expression-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, both the values should have the same data type. You should use something like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN tmp5.Core_Offer IS NULL THEN 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk' 
        ELSE CAST(tmp5.Core_Offer*.75 as varchar(20)) END AS OUTPUT
```

As an example

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tmp5.Core_Offer IS NULL THEN 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk' 
  ELSE CAST(tmp5.Core_Offer*.75 as varchar(20)) END AS [OUTPUT]
from (
  select 100 as Core_Offer
  union all select 1
  union all select 101200
  union all select 250
  union all select null
) tmp5
```

Returns

```
75.00
0.75
75900.00
187.50
Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk
```

Comment: Integers can be NULL, so your first example can be deleted. There is no need for the CAST to check NULL.

Comment: Get the error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'

Comment: @Jebbur then you need to provide a sample of values that can exist in the column `Core_Offer` including min and max values.

Comment: min value 5 and max value 250.  Unless you count the max value being 'Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk'

Comment: I tried that exact code using values of null, 1, 250, 100, 101200.123456789 and they all worked fine and gave the desired output. So there must be something else in the mix.

Comment: @DaleBurrell The only thing I'm thinking is that the values come from a previous case statement which inserted into #TMP5 table.  As such, there are only 20 unique values.  Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk
250
200
150
125
100
90
75
70
50
45
40
30
20
15
13
10
8
5

Comment: So your column in `#temp5` is actually a `varchar` since it can contain "Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk"? Obviously that isn't going to work, as you're mixing datatypes again. Make it an int column and leave it null when you want the final result "Play 15 pts get 5 in Kiosk". Databases don't mix datatypes - only displays want to do that, so want until you actually display it to turn numbers into strings, and keep your columns a single datatype the rest of the time.